# What .NET project/service to use for a background app that runs all the time?

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have to make a program that watches a location on a computer for files and then converts them when new files get put into a specific folder.

Now my question is what kind of Project would be most appropriate for this?
Is **ASP.NET MVC Web Application** a good choice or would I be better of doing a **Windows Service** or **WCF Service** or even **Console App**?

My app needs to run on the same server as another MVC app already runs, and I need to access some database to keep track of what files I have converted.

Comment: Windows Service was created for exactly that purpose.  A scheduled Console Application could also serve as a reasonable fallback for periodic executions.

Comment: Windows service. [Here is a good tutorial to create it](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize Windows task scheduler to periodically run an exe file. In this case the project would be a console app.

A better solution would be to use Windows service. See comments from David & as.if.i.code (tnx btw, you learn something new every day :)